# AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor, Hypervisor and Docker

Tags: docker, amd-processor, docker-for-windows

I have an AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor system and I would like to know if docker for Windows will run and be supported on it

Answer (score -1):

Docker for Windows [runs on Windows 10](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install)

Windows containers [run on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/index)

If your machine can run either operating system then you can run Windows containers